# docker-compose up failing on mac M1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-m1, podman, podman-compose

i have a working docker-compose.yaml file working perfectly using podman-compose on my fedora 35 box.

however, when i try to build the environment using docker-compose on my mac equipped with m1 chip it fails. to be more specific, it fails on [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/sombriks/it-works-on-my-machine/blob/main/app/Dockerfile).

the complete docker-compose file can be seen [here](https://github.com/sombriks/it-works-on-my-machine/blob/main/docker-compose.yaml).

again, it works on linux perfectly.

any guidance is welcome.

Comment: if you can provide the errors you getting, it would be easier for someone identify the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue, it's not an issue with docker on M1 or with docker compose. The base image (`docker.io/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine`) must provide an arm version, which [is not the case for this one](https://hub.docker.com/layers/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/alpine/images/sha256-04f08fd109dab4e753153c6f206620a1767745c0f9f55a97a929930a3f75a65d?context=explore).

[Newer java versions](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/amazoncorretto/17-alpine/images/sha256-df48bf2e183230040890460ddb4359a10aa6c7aad24bd88899482c52053c7e17?context=explore) offer arm64 support.